# Robotlegs wiring up dependencies that belong to a base class

Tags: actionscript-3, robotlegs

I'm using robot legs, I've got a bunch of ServiceResponses that extends a base class and have a dependency on a Parser, IParser. I need to wire in a parser specific to the subclass.  Here's an example:

ModuleConfigResponse extends SimpleServiceResponse and implements IServiceResponse.

The initial part is easy to wire in the context, here's an example:

```
injector.mapClass(IServiceResponse, ModuleConfigResponse);
injector.mapClass(IServiceResponse, SimpleServiceResponse, "roomconfig");
..etc
```

Each Response uses a parser that is used by the baseclass:

```
injector.mapValue(IParser, ModuleConfigParser, "moduleconfig");
injector.mapValue(IParser, RoomConfigParser, "roomconfig");
```

The question is how to tie these together.  The base class could have:

```
[Inject]
public var parser : IParser
```

But I can't define the type ahead of time. Im wondering if there a nice way of wiring this in the context.  For the moment I've decided to wire this up by instanciating responses in a ResponseFactory instead so that I pay pass the parser manually in the constructor.

injector.mapValue(IParser, ModuleConfigParser, "moduleconfig");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that not everything can be mapped in the context, RL trapped me into this way of thinking.  But I've realised that its far better to map a factory to produce these objects which have very specific dependencies, than littler the codebase with marker interfaces or strings :)

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to have the following in your base class:

```
protected var _parser : IParser
```

Then for instance in ModuleConfigResponse

```
[Inject(name='moduleconfig')]
public function set parser( value : IParser ) : void{
    _parser = value;
}
```

But TBH, using named injections is STRONGLY discouraged, you might as well use a marker interface:

```
public interface IModuleConfigParser extends IParser{}
```

the base class stays the same, but ModuleConfigResponse would then use:

```
[Inject]
public function set parser( value : IModuleConfigParser ) : void{
    _parser = value;
}
```

Comment: Mmh I came to the conclusion with another developer that named injections are not so bad depending on the circumstance, where it is clearly seen in a context or factory.  I think that marker interfaces are just as bad. Your first example would be okay, however some responses can use different parsers - re-usability. For now I'll stick to a factory which encapsulates the string names too. :).

Comment: Yeah they're definitely not ideal, but they do have the benefit of CT typechecking. But TBH I have never encountered the situation you describe above, probably due to a different coding/design style, so I just gave an answer to solve the question as-is.